# F# RProvider strange behavior in mgcv package

Tags: r, f#, type-providers

This works:

```
// Helper that evaluates R expression
let evalS (text:string) =
  R.eval(R.parse(namedParams ["text", text ]))

let evalV (text:string) =
  (text |> evalS).Value

//run example from page 8 of http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mgcv/mgcv.pdf
evalV("""
    library(mgcv)
    set.seed(0)
    dat <- gamSim(5,n=200,scale=2)
    """)
let am1 = evalS("b<-gam(y ~ x0 + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3),data=dat)")
let gam_anova1 = evalS("anova(b)")
am1.Value
```

The gam() output is

> Family: gaussian Link function: identity
>
> Formula: y ~ x0 + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3)
>
> Estimated degrees of freedom:
>   1.73 7.07 1.00  total = 13.8
>
> GCV score: 4.578643

and the anova() output is

> Family: gaussian Link function: identity
>
> Formula: y ~ x0 + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3)
>
> Parametric Terms:    df     F p-value x0  3 77.42  <2e-16
>
> Approximate significance of smooth terms:
>           edf Ref.df      F p-value s(x1) 1.729  2.158 45.071  <2e-16 s(x2) 7.069  8.120 49.230  <2e-16 s(x3) 1.000  1.000  0.056   0.812

However, if I try to call the function using the RProvider (an F# type provider) like this:

```
open RProvider.mgcv
R.set_seed(0)
let dat = R.gamSim(5,n=200,scale=2)
let b = R.gam(formula = "y~x0+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3)",data=dat)
R.anova_gam(b)
```

the following error is generated:

> RDotNet.EvaluationException: Error in terms.formula(gf, specials =
>   c("s", "te", "ti", "t2")) :    argument is not a valid model

this error happens on the gam() line. I found the offending line in https://svn.r-project.org/R-packages/trunk/mgcv/R/mgcv.r, but I'm not sure what's going wrong:

```
tf <- terms.formula(gf,specials=c("s","te","ti","t2")) # specials attribute indicates which terms are smooth
```

However, when I combine elements of the two like this:

```
evalV("""
    library(mgcv)
    """)
open RProvider.mgcv
R.set_seed(0)
let dat = R.gamSim(5,n=200,scale=2)
let b = R.gam(formula = evalS("y~x0+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3)"),data=dat)
//let b = R.gam(formula = "y~x0+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3)",data=dat)
R.anova_gam(b)
```

it runs just fine. Note that there are two changes. The first is loading the library, which RProvider I thought was supposed to do for you. The second is using evalS to wrap the formula. I call R.lm without doing this (I just pass in a string representing the formula), so I'm confused as to why this doesn't work the same way.

Can anyone explain this? Is it a bug or just undocumented, but correct, behavior? This is running in ifsharp BTW (https://github.com/BayardRock/IfSharp)

Comment: Running R provider in IfSharp! Very cool :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm only guessing (have not actually tried running the code), but I think the problem is that the `formula` argument of the `gam` function is not actually just a string (which is how you call it in the second case), but a symbolic expression.

R has quite fancy parameter passing mechanism where the function gets a *source code* representation of `y~x0+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3)` so that it can do the analysis based on the expression you specify.

When you pass it through `evalS`, you're calling R to build the symbolic expression, which you then pass to the `gam` function - and so it gets an *expression* rather than a *string*. This is also what happens in the first snippet (where R engine parses the whole string).

As for having to write `library(mgcv)`, I suspect doing that imports some of the symbols used in the symbolic expression like `s(...)`.

Comment: This seems the most likely explanation. So the implication is that this is correct but undocumented (or under-documented) behavior.